# Dynamically Replacing Content with Javascript and Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/bUjx7/42/

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fieldreplace a').click(function () {
        $('#fieldmatch, .fieldgame').hide();
        var region = $(this).data('region');
        $('#' + region).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to make it so clicking one link will replace content in all the cells, and not, as it is, in just one cell.

Help?

Comment: How are you replacing the content in one cell? I dont see the code for that.

Comment: Please look at the jsfiddle link @Starx

Comment: I did, still there are no codes to update an element.

Comment: I'm confused. Does what is happening (after you cycle through "Match" "Game 1" etc.) in the first row "Agents" not qualify as replacing content? @Starx

Comment: Replacing content means replacing or changing your data somehow. You code attaches the the client event of a link and then hides and show a div. There is no replacing involved anywhere. I think you should rewrite the question.

Comment: My apologies for being unclear. In any case, the helpful stranger below who actually understood what I meant already took the liberty of helping me so I don't suppose I'll bother rewriting my OP. Thanks anyway @Starx

Comment: You should edit your post, because your post should be helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

1. I see you have specify `id="fieldgame1"` many times, remember `id` should be unique for every element.
2. You would make use of class selector instead of id selector for selecting all elements.

Now, you would make the cell content with different classes, and use class selector to hide/show them.

HTML

```
<div class="fieldmatch" >2-5</div>
<div class="fieldgame1" >1-6</div>
<div class="fieldgame2" >6-1</div>
<div class="fieldgame3" >2-5</div>
```

Css

```
.fieldgame1, .fieldgame2, .fieldgame3 {
    display:none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fieldreplace a').click(function () {
        $('#fieldmatch, .fieldgame').hide();
        var region = $(this).data('region');
        $('#' + region).show();
    });
});
```

Code example on : http://jsfiddle.net/bUjx7/44/

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the contends of all `td`s like?

```
$('#tableId td').html('content to update on all cells');
```

Comment: Each cell will have a different thing in it though